# Query regarding double in c++

Tags: c++, double

While solving a problem on a particular website, I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    long l{12345678912345};
    char ch{'a'};
    double d{14049.30493};
    std::cout << l <<'\n' << ch <<'\n' << d <<'\n'; 

    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, the output of the double was 14049.3, not the full number. If I explicitly mention

```
std::cout.precision(10);
```

then it prints the full number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: If `std::court.precision(10)` "fixes" the problem, shouldn't it be fairly self explanatory what the problem was?

Comment: @DreamsOfElectricSheep No, for me. Is there a general rule about precision of double used in C++? I could not find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default precision as established by [std::basic_ios::init](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init) is 6, which means the output is limited to 6 digits, unless more digits are needed before the comma.

Note that the `precision` setting takes into account *all digits* (i.e. before *and* after the comma) in determining how many digits after the comma can be printed.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Also: Does it mean that the number also gets truncated in later calculations, if any, with that variable?

Comment: @add349 No it doesn't. It's only the representation on the standard output.

Answer (score -1):

You're doing nothing wrong. In fact, you've fixed the problem already!

`std::cout` tends to round off doubles to avoid printing unusually large decimal numbers. This is why you can set the precision to print a fixed amount of numbers behind the dot.

Comment: Any rule where it rounds off? Does it mean that the number also gets truncated in later calculations, if any, with that variable?

Comment: The double doesn't get rounded off in calculations. As @RustyX said in another answer, `<iostream>` has a default precision of 6